# Notify parent property from child which is dom-repeating

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, polymer-starter-kit

i have initialized property `buyitem` in the child component, and calling `order` function to call it.

```
order() { this.buyitem = "change";}
```

and it is changing in the component level. and in the parent component it is not reflecting. I added `reflectToAttribute: true` and `notify:true` in both components.

Answer (score 2):

In order to reflect to parent value `upward` changes, let say you are in parent-app.html example, use `{{...}}` for two way data binding.( not `[[...]]`)

```
<child-elem buyitem = "{{buyitem}}"></child-elem>
```

into `child-elem` element declare property `notify:true` will be enough:

```
static get properties() { return { 
       buyitem:{
           type:String,
           notify:true
             }
```

but also use `this.set` instead `this.buyitem = "change"`

```
this.set('buyitem', 'change');  // to observable changes.
```